#  Remove any duplicates and its pair

Tags: r

`duplicated()` gives `TRUE` or `FALSE` statement depending if that position is duplicated previously in the vector.  What if I wanted to remove not only the duplicated position, but also all the previous position that it is a duplicate of.

```
a <- c("A", "B", "C")
b <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

`a` contains all the values that will be duplicated and `b` contains the values of `a` and some other values that are not duplicated.

How do I only extract `"D"`?

Comment: Your code example (with two vectors and no clear use for `duplicated()`) doesn't seem to match your description (which refers to "the vector" and "previous position[s]" within it). Does your example need updating/correcting?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, no I think the question is fine, but if you think you can explain better feel free to edit.  If `c(a,b)[!duplicated(c(a,b))]` was used, it would output `[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"`, if `c(a,b)[duplicated(c(a,b))]` was used, it would output `[1] "A" "B" "C"`.  I want only `"D"` to be returned.

I will edit the question to say, 'but also **all** the previous positions that it is a duplicate of.'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is another one:

```
b[!b %in% a]
[1] "D"
```

Comment: I suspect that the original poster does not have `a` and `b` as separate lists. If so, your elegant solution would not be applicable in this case.

Comment: In the example provided by the original poster, two vectors (`a` and `b`) are created, or do I miss something?

Comment: @Kev, With the `%chin%` function from the `data.table` package, jmsigner's answer might see a speed bump: `library(data.table); b[!b %chin% a]` (although the answer is very fast as it is!!)

Comment: @jmsigner and Kev: My mistake, please disregard earlier comment.

Answer (score 4):

If what you really have is a single vector in which some elements are duplicated and some (which you want to keep) aren't, you could try either of these:

```
## Constructing an example that fits your narrative description of the situation
a <- c("A", "B", "C")
b <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
ab <- c(a,b)

# Approach #1
setdiff(ab, ab[duplicated(ab)])
# [1] "D"

# Approach #2 
ab[!(duplicated(ab) | rev(duplicated(rev(ab))))] 
# [1] "D"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some timings to show how solutions posted by @Josh O'Brien, @cogitovita, and @jmsigner perform with a larger dataset:

```
set.seed(123)

a = sample(paste("ID_", seq(1e6), sep=""))
b = sample(a, 9e5, replace=TRUE)
ab = sample(c(a, b))

system.time(res1 <- setdiff(ab, ab[duplicated(ab)]))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.543   0.030   1.563 

system.time(res2 <- ab[!(duplicated(ab) | rev(duplicated(rev(ab))))])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.537   0.042   0.575 

system.time(res3 <- names(table(ab))[table(ab) == 1])
#   user  system elapsed 
# 52.208   0.255  52.218 

system.time(b[!b %in% a])
#user  system elapsed 
#0.098   0.002   0.100 

setequal(res1, res2)
# [1] TRUE
setequal(res1, res3)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: What is y? it is undefined in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
> table(c(a, b))
# A B C D
# 2 2 2 1
> names(table(c(a, b)))[table(c(a, b)) == 1]
# [1] "D"
```

Comment: So this takes the character data and turns it into a frequency table, then the column names with only 1 frequency is extracted.  Very clever.  Do you think this will scale easily with hundreds or thousands of character data in vectors?

Comment: @Kev, it's slow on big data, as @bdemarest shows. `table` takes a lot of time on generating useless information for your case.